# two questions on Gstreamer rtsp-server module

Tags: audio, video, gstreamer

Hi I would like to ask two questions on gst_rtsp_server.

1. I have a pipeline like the following:

   ```
   gchar *pipeline =
         g_strdup_printf ("( udpsrc port=4444 name=src0 "
                          "! queue ! rtpmp2tdepay ! video/mpegts, systemstream=true, packetsize=188  ! aiurdemux  name=demux "
                          " demux.video_0 ! queue ! h264parse name=v !  rtph264pay config-interval=1 name=pay0 pt=96 "
                          " demux.audio_0  !  queue ! aacparse name=a ! rtpmp4gpay name=pay1 pt=97 )");
   ```

   and I have set the service port to be at 8552.

   ```
   g_object_set (server, "service","8552", NULL);
   ```

   However when I checked with my wireshark, I found this for UDP [image: UDP Capture] and TCP Capture [image: TCP Capture]

   So it is true that the port 8552 is associated with RTSP information exchange (DESCRIBE, PLAY TEARDOWN etc) and the underlying media exchange (Audio/Video) port is 40012 and 40013?
2. I have noticed the Gstreamer RTSP will sometimes be in UDP and sometimes in TCP. IS this so? Can I fixed to a particular transport protocol.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps anyone

For 2) gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_protocols (factory, GST_RTSP_LOWER_TRANS_UDP);